# NIntegrate: how to speed up code?

Tags: numerical-integration, performance-tuning

```
a = 4;(* nodes  Х  (-a,a)*)
b = 4;(* nodes У  (-b,b)*)
n = (2 a + 1) ( 2 b + 1);(*all nodes *)
x0 = 2;
y0 = 2;
k = 1/2 // N;
Ax = k/(x0)^2;
Ay = k/(y0)^2;
EE = 2 10^5;
μ = 0.3;
h = 0.8;
Dc = EE*h^3/12/(1 - μ^2) ;
ϕ = {Flatten[Table[Exp[-Ax (x - xi)^2] Exp[-Ay (y - yi)^2], {xi, -a, 
                                a}, {yi, -b, b} ]]};
ϕT = Transpose[ϕ];
solK = Dc/2 Laplacian[(ϕT . ϕ),{x,y}];
K1 = NIntegrate[solK, {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}, 
     Method -> {"MultidimensionalRule", "Generators" -> 5, 
                "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}, PrecisionGoal -> 3, AccuracyGoal -> 3];
```

Hi! I want find deformation (strain) energy for plane by pressure .In one of the steps I need to use `NIntegrate` function so problem with speed of my code when I take (a=6, b=6) it works too slowly!  What can I do to inprove code?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Independent of speed, are you getting the answer your expect?  You are computing a very large array of integrals.

Comment: yes,i get answer that is need

Comment: yes, with a very large array of integrals. I just want to make it faster.I know that Mathematica have function `Compile` can i do smth without it function (Because I'm not good at Parallel Computing) to make code faster or this is better way to use `Compile` ?

Comment: note that `solK` is symmetric, so you  shouldn't integrate redundant terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in the Question runs slowly, because it evaluates `n^2` integrals.  However, all the integrands are of the form

```
Dc Exp[-Ax (x - a1)^2] Exp[-Ay (y - b1)^2] Exp[-Ax (x - a2)^2] Exp[-Ay (y - b2)^2];
```

This generic term can be integrated symbolically in several seconds

```
Integrate[Laplacian[%, {x, y}], {x, -a, a}, {y, -b, b}]

(* Dc (E^((-2*a^2 - a1^2 - a2^2 - 4*b^2 - b1^2 - b2^2)/8)*Sqrt[Pi]*
  (-((2*a + a1 + a2)*E^((-4*a*(a1 + a2) + 8*b^2 + (b1 + b2)^2)/16)*Erf[(2*b - b1 - b2)/4]) - 
   (2*a - a1 - a2)*E^((4*a*(a1 + a2) + 8*b^2 + (b1 + b2)^2)/16)*Erf[(2*b - b1 - b2)/4] + 
   E^((b*(b - b1 - b2))/4)*(E^((4*a^2 + (a1 + a2)^2)/16)*(-((b1 + b2)*(-1 + E^((b*(b1 + b2))/2))) + 2*b*(1 + E^((b*(b1 + b2))/2)))*
      Erf[(-2*a - a1 - a2)/4] - (2*a + a1 + a2)*E^((-4*a*(a1 + a2) + (2*b + b1 + b2)^2)/16)*Erf[(2*b + b1 + b2)/4]) - 
   E^((b*(b - b1 - b2))/4)*(E^((4*a^2 + (a1 + a2)^2)/16)*(-((b1 + b2)*(-1 + E^((b*(b1 + b2))/2))) + 2*b*(1 + E^((b*(b1 + b2))/2)))*
      Erf[(2*a - a1 - a2)/4] + (2*a - a1 - a2)*E^((4*a*(a1 + a2) + (2*b + b1 + b2)^2)/16)*Erf[(2*b + b1 + b2)/4])))/4 *)
```

which can be evaluated by substitution to obtain the desired numerical values.  Note that `k` has been set to `1/2`, rather than `0.5` as in the Question.

**Sidelight**

Defining

```
ϕx = Table[Exp[-Ax (x - xi)^2], {xi, -a, a}];
ϕy = Table[Exp[-Ay (y - yi)^2], {yi, -b, b}];
```

`ϕT . ϕ` is given by

```
Outer[Times, Flatten[Outer[Times, ϕx, ϕy]], Flatten[Outer[Times, ϕx, ϕy]]];
```

Further, if `Flatten` is omitted, which affect only the order of array elements, this last expression becomes

```
Outer[Times, ϕx, ϕy, ϕx, ϕy];
```

or, equivalently (up to a reordering of array elements),

```
Outer[Times, ϕx, ϕx, ϕy, ϕy];
```

Comment: Dear bbgodfrey,thank you very much for useful ideas!

Answer (score 0):

A quick and dirty use of Parallelize gave me a 2.7x speed improvement on my machine (4-core CPU w/ hyperthreading).
But since NIntegrate itself cant be parallelized, I used Map to do the trick

```
K1=Parallelize[NIntegrate[#,{x,-a,a},{y,-b,b},Method->{"MultidimensionalRule","Generators"->5,"SymbolicProcessing"->0},PrecisionGoal->3,AccuracyGoal->3]&/@solK]
```

hope this helps :)

Comment: Thak you!Good idea!